# ASP.NET Core 2 Localization (ViewLocalizer Not Working)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization, .net-core

I have the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddLocalization(o => { o.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
   services.AddMvc(options =>{})
   .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
   .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
 }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
       new CultureInfo("en"),
       new CultureInfo("ko"),
     };
     app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
     {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
      });
      ......
}
```

I have a `Index.cshtml` that has the following (which is inside `/Views/Home/`).

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
......
<h2>@Localizer["QuickLinksTitle"].Value</h2>
```

And I have 2 `.resx` files, `Index.en.resx` and `Index.ko.resx` inside `/Resources/Views/Home`

But the view **always** displays `QuickLinksTitle` instead of the values from the `.resx` file.

Both `.resx`'s have the key `QuickLinksTitle` and corresponding text values but it seems that it never reads anything from any resource files.

I have verified that my browser is indeed sending the right languages `Accept-Language: ko,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8`

My assumption is that if I give `@Localizer['Key']` it should be reading the value of that key and not the actual key.

I understand that MS wants us to do `@Localizer["Some text in default lang"]` and then that has the key for the non default languages but I prefer to have a `.resx` for default lang (english) and one for every other lang.  But right now I haven't even gotten that far to even read from a `.resx` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that MS wants us to do `@Localizer["Some text in default lang"]` and then that has the key for the non default languages but I prefer to have a `.resx` for default lang (English) and one for every other lang.

That's doable. But, you need to follow the convention for using a default language in the `.resx` file.

You have setup the ***default*** language as `en`:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

But you have setup a ***localized*** `.resx` file for `en`:

```
/Resources/Views/Home/Index.en.resx
/Resources/Views/Home/Index.ko.resx
```

It should be a ***default*** `.resx` file for the default language `en`:

```
/Resources/Views/Home/Index.resx
/Resources/Views/Home/Index.ko.resx
```

Comment: It seems my problem was actually `AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)` Changed it to SubFolder and things seem to work.

Comment: I am having same problem but the subfolder did not work for me any ideas ?

Comment: For me it also helped to change it to the `LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder`. But this looks like a bug in asp.net.